# How to distinguish between null and empty string in prompt window?

Tags: javascript, prompt

I have to check (prompt window is obligatory) if a user entered a correct answer on these conditions:

1. If a user entered a correct answer, alert 'you are correct'.
2. If a user enters a wrong answer OR leaves it EMPTY, alert 'you are wrong'
   3  If a user presses the cancel button nothing happens.

```
    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    var result = num1 * num2;
    var userInput = parseInt(prompt('What is ' + num1 + ' * ' + num2 + ' ?'));

    if (userInput === result){
        alert('You are correct!');
    } else if (userInput === '' || userInput !== result) {
        alert('You are wrong!');
    } else if (userInput === null) {
        alert('Cancelled!');
    }
```

What happens is that alert says 'you are wrong' even if I press cancel. I added cancelled alert just for an example. Any suggestions?

Comment: While `prompt()` does indeed return `null` when the user clicks Cancel, this information is lost when passed through `parseInt()`. You should check for the `null` response *before* attempting to parse the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, you are running the return value of `prompt` through `parseInt` **before** you test to see if it is an empty string or null.

Then you aren't distinguishing between null and "not the result".

- Don't `parseInt` before you start your tests.
- Test for `null` **before** you test for `!== result`.
- Test for `userInput === parseInt(result, 10)` (always use a radix with `parseInt`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, how do I handle a situation where a user enters two or more numbers, the correct answer included, and it still says it's a wight answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (userInput === result){
    alert('You are correct!');
} else if (isNaN(userInput)) {
    alert('Cancelled!');
} else if (userInput === '' || userInput !== result) {
    alert('You are wrong!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from `parseInt` will never be strictly equal to `null`. Try testing the `input` before calling `parseInt`.

Here's one way that works:

```js
const
  rand0To9 = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1),
  num1 = rand0To9(),
  num2 = rand0To9(),
  result = num1 * num2,
  input = prompt(`What is ${num1} * ${num2}?`);

if (input !== null){
  alert(`You are ${ parseInt(input, 10) == result ? "correct" : "wrong" }!`);
}
```